# BIOS works, but laptop is not booting. Just goes to a Lenovo logo or a blank screen on a Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ALC6 laptop

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop, liveusb

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ALC6 laptop that I bought listed with a defective SSD. When I got it, put in a new, working confirmed SSD, it still didn't work. After troubleshooting, here's where I'm at:

The laptop can access and enter BIOS setup and change/save any settings, but not load any operating system outside of that (not from an SSD or USB), despite BIOS correctly identifying the amount of RAM, SSD and USB drives attached, so no issues POSTing. It results in a Lenovo Logo (when I try to boot Windows off an SSD) or a blank screen (if I try to boot Linux or something else from a USB). There is nothing further on the screen, however, in some cases the fans engage at that point. I have tried changing various boot and other bios settings, doing full resets, running it without various components plugged in, other than those soldered to the MB, but to no avail. As soon as it leaves BIOS to try to do anything else, it freezes.

What might be some further steps to try, or what might these symptoms be indicative of? Everything I find on the internet seems to either be an earlier problem (not POSTing or no access to BIOS setup/boot order) or, for those that fail at this point, almost always a drive issue, but I can't even boot from working Windows SSDs or Linux USBs.

---

To respond to some questions/comments:

- **It *cannot* be an SSD issue.** The SSD I used has been proven to boot in this exact model laptop with the exact same specs. The contacts are clear, and BIOS can recognize the exact drive name, and that Windows is installed on it. If it was, I would be able to boot to a USB, but I can't.
- **It does not seem to be a battery issue.** I have tried booting without any battery attached, after removing the battery, holding down the power button for a minute, and the plugging in to AC power to boot, but nothing changed.
- **It is not a wireless card issue, nor a keyboard or mouse issue.** Even with no Wif-Fi card inside or the keyboard and/or mouse disconnected, it still didn't boot.

Comment: Can you install Windows fresh on the new SSD (Windows from the Microsoft Media Creation Link)

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion! I installed Windows fresh on the SSD using another computer, then plugged it in to the M.2 slot. The Media Creation Tool, like any OS, won't run on this laptop. It's not an issue with the SSD as far as I can tell.

Comment: The drivers are not the same. Use the USB and delete the partitions on the SSD and install fresh on THIS pc (not another one).

Comment: In fact, the laptop recognized that a Windows SSD was present (!), as when pressing the Novo Button (part of BIOS), I had the option of starting Windows Recovery (but of course, that couldn't boot either, like every other attempt)

Comment: @John Firstly, I installed it on literally an exact same model laptop, so the drivers are identical. Second, no one can install anything on this laptop, since nothing will load beyond BIOS, even the media creation tool, even DOS.

Comment: There must be a hardware error on the problem laptop.

Comment: @John That seems likely, the question is how to identify it, and why it gets past POST/BIOS, but can do literally nothing else.
For a laptop, how might I check for a memory issue on soldered memory, for example? I can't even run MEMTEST, since nothing boots from USB...

Comment: FWIW, I did what I said on an 10 year old X230 and it is humming away just fine in my basement workshop. So your problem machine appears to need service.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same problem with battery failure. I infer that the CPU and GPU are running OK, but when I get too much disk activity, the power failure causes a driver load failure.

In my case, failure to boot correctly followed a long period where the battery was dead but the laptop worked ok while connected to mains supply.

I'm pretty sure it was a battery failure in my case, because:

1. The battery failed.
2. When I replaced the battery boot completed and the laptop worked again.

Comment: Interesting. I had already tried (but tried again after seeing your post) to remove the battery, drain all power, and the run it plugged in to AC power, but nothing changed - it still didn't boot.